# ES6 template gives a syntax error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying my first steps in learning ES6 and right now am facing a few issues with templates.

JavaScript looks like this:

```
"use strict"

let name = 'John';

function makeUpperCase(word){
    return word.toUpperCase();
}

let template = '<h1>${makeUpperCase('Hello')} ${name} Developer</h1><p>paragraph comes here</p>';

document.getElementById('template').innerHTML = template;
```

It seems like my variables are not being read:

```
'<h1>${makeUpperCase('Hello')} ${name} Developer</h1><p>paragraph comes here</p>';
```

So when I load the page a see an error in my console saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

My index.html is as simple as this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning ES6</title>
</head>
<body>      
    <header>
        <h1 id="heading">Learning ES6</h1>
        <p>With Sidney de Sousa</p>
    </header>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="template">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am supposed to see a heading one saying: HELLO John Developer.

Hope you can help

Comment: Templates use the backtick `\`` to define templates, so your code would be: `\`<h1>${makeUpperCase('Hello')} ${name} Developer</h1><p>paragraph comes here</p>\`;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the single quote `'` hence it is interpreted as a string. (Also the string is being dissected when the function is used with value `'HELLO'` - here the first `'` is matched with the opening single quote - hence `HELLO` is treated as a variable in javascript, which is not defined.)

You should be using the back tick ` like this

```
let template = `<h1>${makeUpperCase('Hello')} ${name} Developer</h1><p>paragraph comes here</p>`;
```

Comment: Was complete unaware of that detail. Am using the back tick now and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using backticks (`) instead of regular quotes (')?

Here is the example:

```
const str = `Hi, my name is ${userName}`;
```

Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for details about template literals in ES6.